# Which sql query will be formed while using skip and take in entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am using below query to get results from SQL Server using Entity Framework:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get product list 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<Products> GetProductList(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    return (from p in ctx.Products
            select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

How it will internally work? I mean which query will be executed in database?

Also is it using Lazy Loading by default?

Comment: How about using a sql profiler and figure yourselves

Comment: Will the code you posted even work without an `order by`?

Comment: Yes by default EF uses lazyloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: the code you posted will only throw an exception:

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

---

**Longer answer**: So assuming you are putting an `OrderBy` in to your code, and your Entity Framework is targetting a recent release of SQL Server (i.e. SQL2012 or newer), you will get SQL looking something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Column2] AS [Column2], 
    [Extent1].[Column3] AS [Column3], 
    [Extent1].[Column4] AS [Column4], 
        --etc
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
    OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Note the last line of the query, it says skip 5 rows and take the next 4, using the [`OFFSET/FETCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) syntax.

As for the lazy loading question, there is nothing in here to suggest you have disabled it so it will be *on* by default.